# List item inside model always null on post - Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to post model which contains **List<>** item looks like below:

```
public class AddSubscriptionPlanModel
{
    public AddSubscriptionPlanModel()
    {
        AllFeatures = new List<Feature>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionPlanId { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No Of Users")]
    public int? NoOfUsers { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Duration Type")]
    public DurationType DurationType { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionPlanTrailId { get; set; }
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedUtc { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }    
    public List<Feature> AllFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

I am populating all required fields on get method and feeding List from database

```
public ActionResult Mapping(int id)
{        
    var features = FeatureManager.GetAllFeatures();
    var model = new Ejyle.DevAccelerate.Web.App.Models.SubscriptionPlan.AddSubscriptionPlanModel();

    model.AllFeatures = features;
    model.Id = id;
    model.SubscriptionId = id;
    model.NoOfUsers = 20;
    model.SubscriptionPlanId = 1;
    model.SubscriptionPlanTrailId = 1;
    model.Amount = 1000;
    model.CreatedBy = 1;
    model.LastUpdatedBy = 1;
    model.FeatureId = 1;
    model.Duration = 20;

    return View(model);
}
```

And my view code looks like below :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Mapping", "SubscriptionPlans", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Amount)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Duration)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeatureId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastUpdatedBy)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NoOfUsers)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriptionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriptionPlanId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriptionPlanTrailId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures)
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i=0; i < Model.AllFeatures.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].IsActive)
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].IsActive)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
}
```

On View, the list items rendered properly and even I am able to edit those fields.
But On post, all properties have the value except **AllFeatures** list item property which always shows count = 0.

Edit 1: This is how my view looks like while rendering features

[image]

Edit 2:

Signature of the method posting to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Mapping(AddSubscriptionPlanModel model)
{       
}
```

Comment: can you give us a piece of final HTML generated for the the loop. I imagine with the combination of hidden field and editorfield for the same property, it may be having a hard time mapping a strongly typed object.

Comment: Why do you need to send the `AllFeatures` to the browser and then why do you need to post this back to the server?

Comment: User will be able yo edit all features in the view and post back @CodingYoshi

Comment: @TravisActon I tried to preserve the value in all properties. I tried both hidden for and as well as EditFor, But both failed to preserve values from view to controller.

Comment: Yes, but in the view you posted on here, you are using an ediitfor and a hiddenfor for the same model property. Remove the hiddenfor and see what happens, I imagine it can have issues trying to auto bind when you have duplicate properties as that.

Comment: @TravisActon I just posted that code to make it clear that even I tried that. But obviously, I tried all 3  -> without hidden, with hidden and only EditorFor, All 3 fails to preserve List item value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But On post, all properties have the value except AllFeatures list item property which always shows count = 0.

`AllFeatures` is a generic list of `Feature`. When you do this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures)
```

The Razor view engine will render this:

```
<input id="AllFeatures" 
       name="AllFeatures" 
       type="hidden" 
       value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Feature]">
       <!--Where Namespace is the Namespace where Feature is defined. -->
```

In other words, `HiddenFor` calls the `ToString()` on the item and simply puts that into the `input` tag's `value` attribute.

**What happens upon POST**

When you post the form, the `DefaultModelBinder` is looking for a property named `AllFeatures` but of type `string` so it can assign this to it:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Feature]
```

It does not find one since your model does not have `AllFeatures` of type `string`, so it simply ignores it and binds all the other properties.

> AllFeatures list item property which always shows count = 0.

Yes, it will and this is not the `AllFeatures` list which you posted but the one from the constructor which clearly is an empty list with a count 0:

```
public AddSubscriptionPlanModel()
{
    AllFeatures = new List<Feature>();
}
```

I am not sure why you are sending all the features to the client (browser) and then you need to post it back to the server.

**Solution**

To fix the issue, simply remove this line:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures)
```

Now it will not cause any confusion during binding and MVC will bind the items in the loop to the `AllFeatures` property.

In fact, the only code you really need, as far as I can tell from your question is this(I could be wrong if you need the hidden fields for some other reason. But if you just want the user to edit the AllFeatures, you do not need any of the hidden fields):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllFeatures.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].IsActive)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: User will be able yo edit all features in the view and post back

Comment: @VigneshwaranMarkandan ok! May I see the signature of the action you are posting to?

Comment: Sure. [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Mapping(AddSubscriptionPlanModel model)
{       
}.  I edited post for you, kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might be the nested property. You may want to review the posted form and see what it looks like.

Your markup looks correct assuming that the model binding would work for a nested property - which I am not sure it does. (Just to make sure I searched for and found this old Haack post that indicates you're doing it right: [Haack Post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/))

As a workaround (and POC), you can try the following: Add a new parameter to your action for your features, post it like your doing now but not nested (so you can't use the Model For HTML helpers) and then in the controller, you can set it back to your main object's features property.

Comment: That post talks about passing Model List<> as a parameter. And the workaround you are talking about will be the alternative and not the solution for the above problem.

Comment: Yes, that's true :)

Answer (score 1):

This how to do it, as in the context of binding to a list from a view is incorrect.

View:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.AddSubscriptionPlanModel
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Mapping</title>
</head>
<body>
    @*I am using controller home*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Mapping", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Amount)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Duration)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeatureId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastUpdatedBy)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NoOfUsers)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriptionId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriptionPlanId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubscriptionPlanTrailId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures)
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllFeatures.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @*BE SURE to get rid of these*@
                        @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Id)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Name)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].IsActive)*@
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AllFeatures[i].IsActive)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Mapping(AddSubscriptionPlanModel addSubscriptionModel, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var AllFeatures = String.Empty;
        var index = "AllFeatures[";
        foreach (var item in formCollection)
        {
            if (item.ToString().Contains(index))
            {
                AllFeatures += " " + formCollection.GetValues(item.ToString())[0];
            }
        }

        //put breakpoint here to see userValues
```

Comment: Why should I need FormCollection if I have the model ?

Comment: I researched for a long time and could not bind to AllFeatures, as it is a collection.  I can display a dropdown as a collection and the user can select one, but I could not bind the way you want.