# Why When passing a Model, with a list of child objects, to a Controller the list of child objects is not passed through?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 Model classes:

```
public class ModelWithList 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<SetOfGroups> GroupSets { get; set; }
}

public class SetOfGroups
{
    List<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit my form all the fields are pass through from `ModelWithList` except for the GroupSets.

Normally I would use a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupSets)` for properties that aren't passed through but this can't be done with lists of custom models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have this model setup:

```
public class ModelWithList {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<SetOfGroups> GroupSets { get; set; }
}

public class SetOfGroups
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use a `for` loop to iterate `GroupSets` and assign its index for every numeric type/`string`/`DateTime` (including `Nullable<T>`) properties it has:

```
@model ModelWithList

@* other code *@

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.GroupSets.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupSets[i].GroupId)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupSets[i].GroupName)
}
```

Next, assume that you're moving `SetOfGroups` properties and create a new list:

```
public class SetOfGroups
{
    List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should add another `for` loop to bind them:

```
@model ModelWithList

@* other code *@

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.GroupSets.Count; i++)
{
    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.GroupSets[i].Groups.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupSets[i].Groups[j].GroupId)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupSets[i].Groups[j].GroupName)
    }
}
```

Although it may possible to add nested lists into view like above sample, the loops to render HTML helpers will become more complex and should be avoided.

**Important Note:**

You **should not** assign a `HiddenFor` to a `List<T>` like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GroupSets)
```

because Razor implicitly calls `ToString()` method to that `List<T>` object, resulting in fully-qualified name of the list inserted to the `value` attribute and the binding will ignore it because `GroupSets` is not a `string` property:

```
<input id="GroupSets" name="GroupSets" type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectNamespace.Models.SetOfGroups]">
```

Related issue:

[List item inside model always null on post - Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989007/list-item-inside-model-always-null-on-post-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realize I would have to put in a hidden field for each property I thought there might have been a better way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When I add the `HiddenFor` for each property it passes perfectly however when I use a partial view with `Html.RenderPartial("_GroupSetPartial", GroupSets[i]);` that includes`EditorFor` the properties don't pass through to the controller.

Comment: What is the contents inside `_GroupSetPartial`? Are you attempting to render partial view multiple times based from list index? Probably you should pass `GroupSets` without indexing and set partial view model as `IEnumerable<SetOfGroups>`.